# Unconsumed yeast nutrients before bottling

Tags: fermentation, yeast, bottling, yeast-nutrient

I have a batch of a brown ale (15L) from a kit, where after some weeks, I got 1.016 and the fermentation stopped. To restart the fermentation I added two teaspoons of yeast nutrients. After one day, it stopped again, now the FG is 1.012. Then I tried two more teaspoons of yeast nutrients, and the fermentation didn't restart this time, so no bubbles in the airlock.

Now, after 5 days, my idea is just bottle the beer as it is. My concern is, as I need to add some sugar just before bottling, there is any risk to restart he fermentation in the bottle due to the presence of unconsumed yeast nutrients?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be safe to bottle.

You used an awful lot of nutrient.  I can see that it helped, but you probably only needed about one teaspoon maximum; the rest of it was truly not useful.  As such you saw the initial drop from 1.016 to 1.012, and that is as far as it will go.

You can prime and bottle the batch now as normal.  It should turn out well.  You might sense a salty flavor in the finished beer from the high level of nutrient, I am not sure but hopefully not.